# What kind of algebraic structure is a group with the conjugation as a second operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

It is interesting in a group that conjugation $(x,y)\mapsto x^y:=y^{-1}xy$ behaves like exponentation among real numbers:

1. $(xy)^z=x^zy^z$
2. $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$

That is, real numbers with multiplication and exponentation forms the same algebraic structure as a group with multiplication and conjugation  Is there a name for this algebraic structure?

Comment: Strikes me as a ring like structure.

Comment: If you want your operations to be well defined you should restrict them to non-negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The two laws of exponentiation you noted are both studied in group theory not as an operation on a set but rather in the context of *group actions*.

The second law, $(x^y)^z = x^{yz}$, is saying that a group *acts* on itself. This is a particular instance of a more general situation, where a group could be acting on a set/vector space/other group.

The first law, $(xy)^z = x^z y^z$, is saying that this action r*espects the structure* of the set on which the group acts. In your case, the axiom is saying that the action respects multiplication on the group.

In a similar way, you could have a group action on a vector space by linear transformations, and the conditions for this to hold would be expressible in terms of analogous axioms you noted for a group acting on itself.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to darko's answer, a group acting on itself by conjugation is a special case of **crossed module**.

A crossed module is defined by

- two groups $G$ and $H$
- a group homomorphism $\partial : G\to H$
- an group action of $H$ on $G$, denoted $g^h$ for all $g\in G$ and $h\in H$, which respects the group structure of $G$ (as explained in darko's answer)

satisfying two axioms for all $g,g'\in G$ and $h\in H$:

1. $\partial (g^h) = h^{-1}\partial(g)h$
2. $g^{\partial (g')}=g'^{-1}gg'$ (this is called Peiffer's identity).

When $G=H$, $\partial(g)=g$ and $g^h=h^{-1}gh$, these two axioms are trivially satisfied.